# How to render a generic loading screen between page views using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I basically have this currently:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom'

const Component = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [isWaiting, setIsWaiting] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setIsWaiting(false), 1000)
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFonts.then(() => setIsLoading(false))
  })

  if (isLoading || isWaiting) return 'Loading...'

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/one'>
          <One />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/two'>
          <Two />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do with this is, on *hard-browser-page-refresh*, show a loader for *at least 1* second (so it is consistent, and later I will do a fade in transition) as the fonts I need load, which could take upwards of 5 seconds. Once everything is loaded, then show the screen.

What I would *like* for it to do as well though, is **only show this loading page once, on hard refresh**. When the user clicks a `<Link to='/one'>One</Link>` sort of link, I would expect for it to *NOT* cause a full re-render of this top-level "App" component with all the routes and the router defined. However, what it's doing is re-rendering the whole component above, and causing the timer to execute every click of a router `<Link to...>`... I don't understand why this isn't working like you'd expect. You'd expect for `<Link to='/one'>One</Link>` to do a non-hard-page-change to the new URL, load the content from the routes, but **NOT** do a full component rebuild and cause the loader to show again.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get it to not show the loader every time it switches pages using `<Link to...>` from `react-router`?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue with your setup (but I can only guess, what `loadFonts` does). Can you provide a full example, that does the described thing? [This was my try at recreating](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-hill-4w07z?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @JosefWittmann Yeah it looks like it works [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-mendel-ybjd7), hmm, `loadFonts` is basically doing [this](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/fd3352c88bc4fb9e38970fc25c013d26) from [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader). Could webfontloader be replacing the DOM or something? My HTML file is [this](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/7e9946b42bf7d5d86a605a25c99b6022).

Comment: @JosefWittmann you can see it in action [here](https://leaf.surf/). If you keep scrolling to the bottom to click a language, it will show you the loader icon (the logo) for a second every time. I am using `<Link to.../>` when clicking a language if you'll see in the debugger.

Comment: @JosefWittmann any ideas?

Comment: I'll look at it the coming days

Comment: I had a look at [leaf.surf](https://leaf.surf/) and when clicking the language links, my browser does a page refresh (also seen in the network tab). The problem seems to lie with the setup of `react-router` (the links don't get handled by the library). Are you able to provide the code to that (or even better, an example where the faulty behaviour is reproduced)?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: No haha, not yet.

Comment: For me to help you, I would need to see the source code where the issue can be reproduced, since in your examples it always worked as it should...